# Extending all my Mongoid documents with an instance method

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I want to extend **all** my `Mongoid::Document`'s with an instance method. Instead of making a module and including it to each `Mongoid::Document` I want to extend, there should be another way.

For example, for the ruby class Array I would simply reopen this class and add the methods I want:

```
class Array
  def my_new_method
    #....
  end
end
```

But how do I that for `Mongoid::Document`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to open a class as you did with Array, better to do it like this:

```
module MyNewMethodable
  def my_new_method( *args )
    fail ArgumentError, "not the right number of arguments"
    #....
  rescue => error
    if MyNewMethodable::Error
      puts "because then users of your module will know where to look for the fault"
    else
      raise error
    end
  end

  class Error < StandardError; end
  class ArgumentError < Error; end

end


class Array
  include MyNewMethodable
end
```

To do this for Mongoid::Document

```
class Mongoid::Document
  include MyNewMethodable
end
```

But, it says [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html)

> Documents are the core objects in Mongoid and any object that is to be persisted to the database must include Mongoid::Document.

So it's already being included into classes that you've defined. Therefore I would suggest you include your module into your classes, not into `Mongoid::Document`. e.g.

```
class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  include MyNewMethodable
end
```

Comment: `Documents are the core objects in Mongoid and any object that is to be persisted to the database must include Mongoid::Document.` I'm not getting this. why should I do `class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  include MyNewMethodable
end`?

Comment: Because that's what the documentation says. I'm not a mongoid user, (I don't like pain;) my answer is from a Ruby perspective and based on the docs, each example of which gives the `Mongoid::Document` class being included into another class. If you wish to mixin your own methods then the rule of thumb is to do it to your own classes, not those of an external library, because it could have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way

```
module Mongoid::Document
    def self.validate
        ...
    end
end
```

However, I would refrain from opening an external module (even thou this seems) to be a common thing to do in the ruby community. What is to say against to include your own module explicitly?